# Docker private registry can't find tags when pulling

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have setup samalba/docker-registry from github source code following official instructions, everything seems to be working fine on the installation, but when it comes to pull previously pushed images I'm getting some errors, let me explain myself:

I have ubuntu:12.04 image on my development machine and I have created a Dockerfile with the intention of creating a base image for my company based on ubuntu:12.04, to build this image I run this command: (docker-index.my.com is my private repository)

```
docker build -t docker-index.my.com/base .
```

or this one:

```
docker build -t docker-index.my.com/base:1.0 .
```

to push the images I use:

```
docker push docker-index.my.com/base:1.0
```

with or without the version tag (:1.0)

On other PC when I try to pull somehow those images from the private repository I get the following:

```
docker run -i -t docker-index.my.com/base /bin/bash
```

which outputs:

```
Unable to find image 'docker-index.my.com/base' locally
Pulling repository docker-index.my.com/base
2014/04/22 09:00:38 Error: No such image: docker-index.my.com/base (tag: latest)
```

Basically this is my workflow.
I have checked and docker-registry seems to have the image with the tag I used to push it, and also it seems to be receiving the request from the docker clients but I can get the pulls working whether I use tag or not.
Am I missing something here? what can it do to find/fix the problem?

Comment: You mention that you use "other PC" to pull. Could it be that you are using some proxying mechanism that is interfering with the requests? For example, nginx has a default upload size of 1M...

Comment: I wish! but is not in may case I'm using exact the same nginx suggested configuration from samalba

Comment: I can not find your samalba reference, but I had exactly the same problem and it was nginx miss-configured. A quick way to check for that is to try exposing the  port directly on the outside network interface, without reverse-proxying (and tagging the images correspondingly).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the image name. Docker wait for a name compose by the hostname, follow by the port and terminate by the image name like this : myhost:5000/myrepo/myimage (and if necessary follow by :X.X for the version).

With this name "docker-index.my.com/base" i think Docker can't understand that this image must be push on a private registry.